# Visual tools to help design rails apps?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a junior rails developer attempting to make my first real app. I know everything I need to do in terms of code but I keep running into these very frustrating design blocks. I know basic HTML and CSS but I don't know how to design a website using purely those tools yet. Are there any web tools that allow me to visually design a website by moving things around on a page. I think my friend used google chrome to do something like that but i'm not sure how. I'm feeling pretty overwhelmed right now because I know what I need to do but have no idea how to do it. My rails app uses so many frameworks and scalpels that I can't really play around and try to design on me own without messing something up.

I tried using bootstrap but once I installed the gem it just added layers of HTML to my page. It looks nicer now but it is so complex that I have no idea how to change anything with disrupting the entire flow.

Answer (score 0):

google `WYSIWYG html editor`.  It seems that's what you're looking for.  I doubt anything is integrated with rails so you'll still have to plug in your dynamic content.